# Is the root filesystem unmounted during a Linux shutdown?

Tags: linux, shutdown, root-filesystem

If the root filesystem is unmounted, then how can `init` be accessed to run the last few steps that occur afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

PID 1 can be run from a RAM-based filesystem.  For example systemd + dracut can `pivot_root` into a [tmpfs](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.20/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt) during shutdown.  [dracut-shutdown.service(8)](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/dracut-core/dracut-shutdown.service.8.en.html) has some more information about this.

Otherwise, you remount the remaining filesystems as read-only.  After remounting read-only, the filesystem is clean.  It is consistent on-disk; requires no repair operations; has no remaining writes cached or queued up in RAM.

[`umount /` is even interpreted the same as `mount / -o remount,ro`.  Although that does not happen on other unix-likes; it is a Linux-specific quirk :-).](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466535/why-does-the-linux-kernel-support-umount)

Answer (score 1):

`init` is the first process to be executed after the kernel was loaded and the last to "shut down the lights" - figuratively spoken.
The kernel does not need `/` to be mounted to run `init`, as it can be run completely from memory.
"Live" distributions are running almost completely from memory and there are even some, whose cd/dvd/usbstick/floppy you can even remove from the pc after the system was loaded into memory.

Now to the question in the title of your question: yes, it is unmounted on most distributions - other remount `/` read-only.

More information can be found in `/etc/inittab` (if the system is running with sysvinit) of your system and for example on http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Run_Levels

On systemd you can view which objects are evaluated with `systemctl list-dependencies --after systemd-halt.service`.

Comment: And distribtions take care that none of the tasks they want to do after unmounting `/` require filesystem access.

Comment: RedHat 6, for example, remounts `/` readonly (`/etc/rc.d/rc0.d/S01halt`).

Comment: what I was trying to figure out right now: how can one tell what happens with systemd? at least on my ubuntu there is no `/etc/inittab`

Comment: The `systemd-shutdown` manpage may provide guidance.  In particular it mentions:      It is necessary to have this code in a separate binary because       otherwise rebooting after an upgrade might be broken -- the running PID       1 could still depend on libraries which are not available any more,       thus keeping the file system busy, which then cannot be re-mounted       read-only.

Comment: `systemctl list-dependencies --after systemd-halt.service` got me a tree of units which are run/stopped/umounted after a `shutdown` was initiated.

The man-page @StephenHarris mentioned led me to the explanation of `systemd-halt.service` and its friends `systemd-poweroff.service`, `systemd-reboot.service` and `systemd-kexec.service`. Which helped me with the `list-dependencies` command. Thanks for that.

Comment: The kernel does need `/` to be mounted to run `init`, of course. It can be run from memory, if `/` is in memory. And while `init` is running, the filesystem it was loaded from cannot be unmounted.